# Definition of Reverse proxying and Screen Scraping in Portal context

Tags: liferay, portal

I'm not sure if these terminologies are correct in a Portal context.

By Portal I mean a JSR-286 compliant portal framework like Liferay or Jetspeed and the query is related to this portlet available from Liferay.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Proxy+Portlet

Is "Reverse Proxying" the same as "Screen Scraping" because in both cases the Portal acts as an intermediary and (optionally) transforms a downstream request before giving the response back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the two behaviours (proxying and scraping) have common features, the intent is different. Screen scraping is typically reading the page and attempting to extract data or meaning from the page before using that data somewhere else. That may result in a page being displayed including the scraped information, but it could be used for any process really.

If instead you want to get an external resource (such as a page) and plug that into a Liferay generated page as portlet content, you would take the entire page content, except that the Portlet 1.0 and 2.0 specs place restrictions and other rules on what can be added (eg cannot include html, head or body tags) and other behaviour that it must conform to. The easiest way to accomplish this is to include it as an iframe, but the portletbridge project aims to wrap incoming content and massage the content to be valid in a portlet context, as well as manage other aspects of the remote page such as css, links and authentication so that the resulting portlet integrates cleanly with the rest of the page and the portal application as a whole.

Comment: So the Portletbridge implies "web proxying" ?

Comment: to my knowledge, yes. From the portletbridge site: "The Portlet Bridge Portlet is a web clipping proxy portlet that allows web application be hosted as portlets. See the PortletBridge Portlet project for more information. The portlet bridge portlet makes downstream HTTP calls and uses CyberNeko and XSLT to do the web clipping."